# Android/Java Repeat Button Click

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I am writing my first android application, and am trying to write an app where you simply click a button to display a message, and can do so as many times as you want. So far I have:

```
public class MyProject extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tv.setText("Hello World!");
            setContentView(tv);
            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {setContentView(R.layout.main);}}, 2000);     
        }
        });
    }
}
```

However doing it this way, when I get back to my main screen and click on the button again...nothing happens. How can I get repeated button clicks to repeat the behaviour?

Comment: whats the purpose of calling setContentView() again n again???

Comment: I would suggest using a ViewFlipper instead of repeatedly setting separate views via setContentView

Comment: So, setting a ViewFlipper will fix the problem, or is your suggestion just a comment on style/best practice? This is my first android app, and I am not very well versed in Java, so I'm not really sure what I am doing at all haha =P

Answer (score 2):

Your example is very simple and, from what I understand, no multithreading is needed.

You just have to initialize your layout one time, after that you can update the content of the single views.

So... this will set "hello world" string on every button click, you will not notice any difference because the string is always the same :D

```
public class MyProject extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // this is needed one time only
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // add your textview in xml
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tv.setText("Hello World!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To do something more fun you can set a counter to update on every click, this way the textview change will be noticeable are more fun!!

```
int i = 0;
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        tv.setText("you have reached " + i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way, I get:

local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final           i++;

But when I declare it final, it complains and tells me it can't edit it because its final!

Comment: Never mind, I solved that problem by bringing int i into the onClickListener loop.

Comment: However, this method doesn't automatically bring me back to the main layout. When I integrated the two, I still had the same problem of not being able to click the button again and have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are calling `setContentView` to replace the entire current view with a `TextView` containing "Hello World!"  Then after two seconds you `setContentView` again to set it back to the main layout.  Since `OnCreate` is only called once when the activity is created, the OnClickListener is never set again.

This code will do what you are looking for.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello World!");
        setContentView(tv);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                init();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

You may notice that `OnClick` is a separate method in my example.  This is because I implemented the interface `View.OnClickListener`.  I was able to write the implemented method as part of my class and then pass `this` as an argument to `setOnClickListener`.  I'm explaining this because you mentioned you are new to Java.

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  gpasci is correct in that you normally don't use `setContentView` in this way.  Although it works perfectly fine, in more complex examples you will want to define your `TextView` in xml as you did with your button.  Also, if you accept my answer by clicking the check mark it will help you get more answers in the future.  Plus I like internet points.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView txt;
// our handler
 Handler handler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

//display each item in a single line
  txt.setText(txt.getText()+"Item "+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
     }
 };
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
              // create a new thread
  Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     try {
     Thread.sleep(1000);      
     b.putString("My Key", "My Value: "+String.valueOf(i));
    // send message to the handler with the current message handler          

      handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
     } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.v("Error", e.toString());
     }
    }
   }
  });

  background.start();
 }
}
```

Note:Handler one type of thread not udpate any UI here
[Take an example from here](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-1-handlers/)